# Magento fill cart from external script with different storeviews

Tags: magento, store, cart

I have a small script, which fills my magento shopping cart with products. It's used for a quickorder form. So it gets called with /quickorder.php?sku1=123&qty1=1&sku2=124&qty2=1 etc.
It's working well for my default store, but for the second store, it seems as it always wants to fill the default shopping cart. At least it redirects me to the default cart url.

How can I get this working to add products to my cart whatever store I'm currently in?

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend')); // Session erzeugen         

$Cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); // Instanz zum Warenkorb

for ($count=1; $_POST['sku'.$count]!=''; $count++) {

$sku = $_POST['sku'.$count];
$qty = $_POST['qty'.$count];
$catprod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product_id = $catprod->getIdBySku($sku);

if ($product_id) {

    $ProdObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($product_id); // Produkt laden

    $Cart->addProduct($ProdObj, $qty); // Produkt in den Warenkorb einfügen  

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess('Artikelnummer "'.$sku.'" wurde '.$qty.'x hinzugef&uuml;gt.');

} else Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError('Artikelnummer "'.$sku.'" wurde nicht gefunden.');
}
$Cart->save(); // Warenkorb speichern   

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

header('Location: '. Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart')); 

?>
```

Comment: where did you generate this url string? is this automatic or just a simple prefix? I mean `/quickorder.php?`

Comment: it's called from a form on a cms page inside magento

Answer (score 0):

You can get store id by product, like below :

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product_id = $productModel->load($object->getId());
$store_id = $product_id->getStoreId();
```